# Mapping torus with homotopic homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose I define the mapping torus $M_f$ in the usual way by identifying $(x, 0)$ and $(f(x), 1)$.  If I have a homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow X$ and another homeomorphism $f': X \rightarrow X$ that are homotopic, are the spaces $M_f$ and $M_{f'}$ necessarily homeomorphic?

Comment: Do you mean simply homotopic or homotopic through homeomorphisms? In the first case the answer is no, take for instance $X=[0,1]$ and $f=\mathrm{id}$ and $g=1-\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: For instance, in $S^1$ the identity and antipodal maps are homotopic and happen to give the same mapping torus.  Is this coincidence?

Comment: They are homotopic through homeomorphisms though. This is more restrictive than simply being homotopic in general. Do you see why the example I gave in my previous comment is a counter example?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by homotopic through homeomorphisms?

Comment: I mean a homotopy $H:X\times[0,1]\to X$ such that for all $t$, $H_t$ is a homeomorphism of $X$. In the case of the identity and the antipodal map of the sphere, you can take the homotopy $H(z,t)=e^{it\pi}z$, which is a homotopy through homeomorphisms.

Comment: Got it.  Does a homotopy through homeomorphism then imply the mapping tori are the same?

Comment: I don't know to be honest, but it seems like a good condition to impose.

Comment: Do you know how to show the mapping torus for the antipodal map then if this is not a valid theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for homotopic homeomorphisms isn't enough: if one takes $X=[0,1]$ and $f=\mathrm{id}$ and $g=1-f$, then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic homeomorphisms, but the mapping cylinder of $f$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times[0,1]$ while the mapping cylinder of $g$ is homeomorphic to the Moebius strip. These spaces aren't homeomorphic.

---

Suppose $X$ locally compact Hausdorff and $Y$ Hausdorff, then a homotopy
$$h:X\times [0,1]\to Y$$ is the same as a continuous path
$$\widehat{h}:[0,1]\to C(X,Y)$$ (This is a special case of the [exponential law for spaces](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces#general_exponential_laws)
where the set $C(X,Y)$ of continuous maps $X\to Y$ is equipped with the [compact open topology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact-open+topology). By a [result of Arens](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58690/compact-open-topology-on-mathrmhomeox/61430#61430), if $X$ is locally compact locally connected (or more trivially, if $X$ is compact), the subset of homeomorphisms $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\subset C(X,X)$ forms a topological group (composition is easily seen to be continuous, but the operation $\mathrm{inv}:f\mapsto f^{-1}$ may not be).

---

From now on $X$ is either compact or locally compact locally connected, so that the map $\mathrm{inv}:f\mapsto f^{-1}$ is a continuous one, and that the homotopy $H$ through homeomorphisms corresponds to a continuous path in $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$. Suppose $H$ is a homotopy through homeomorphisms from $f$ to $g$. Consider the map
$$C:X\times [0,1]\to X\times[0,1],(x,t)\mapsto(H_t(x),t)$$
is a homeomorphism with inverse
$$C':X\times [0,1]\to X\times[0,1],(x,t)\mapsto(\mathrm{inv}(H_t)(x),t)$$
then the map $D=C\circ(f^{-1}\times\mathrm{id}_{[0,1]})$ is a homeomorphism of $X\times[0,1]$, which satisfies for all $x\in X$, $D(x,0)=(x,0)$ and $D(f(x),1)=(g(x),1)$.
This homeomorphism induces a homeomorphism between the mapping tori.

Comment: Ok, there are some mistakes in the formulas, I'll get to them tomotopy.

Comment: Why is it $C'$ not $C$?

Comment: @YonKim corrected the formulas.